# What is the rationale for the United Kingdom statistics body not allowing black people to identify as having an English ethnicity in its surveys?

Tags: united-kingdom, demographics, census

**Ethnicity**

The concept of *ethnicity* [has been described](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKHL/1982/7.html) by the UK's highest court in this way

> For a group to constitute an ethnic group... it must, in my opinion, regard itself, and be regarded by others,
> as a distinct community by virtue of certain characteristics. Some of
> these characteristics are essential; others are not essential but one
> or more of them will commonly be found... The conditions which appear
> to me to be essential are these: — (1) a long shared history, of which
> the group is conscious as distinguishing it from other groups, and the
> memory of which it keeps alive; (2) a cultural tradition of its own,
> including family and social customs and manners... In addition to those
> two essential characteristics the following characteristics are, in my
> opinion, relevant; (3) either a common geographical origin, or descent
> from a small number of common ancestors; (4) a common language, not
> necessarily peculiar to the group; (5) a common literature peculiar
> to the group; (6) a common religion... (7)
> being a minority or being an oppressed or a dominant group within a
> larger community, for example a conquered people (say, the inhabitants
> of England shortly after the Norman conquest) and their conquerors
> might both be ethnic groups.
>
> A group defined by reference to enough of these characteristics would
> be capable of including... for example, persons who marry into
> the group... Provided a person who joins the
> group feels himself or herself to be a member of it, and is accepted
> by other members, then he is... a member...
>
> In my opinion, it is possible for a person to fall into a particular
> racial group either by birth or by adherence, and it makes no
> difference... by which route he
> finds his way into the group...
>
> ...the word " ethnic " is of Greek origin, being derived from the
> Greek word " ethnos ", the basic meaning of which appears to have been
> simply " a group " not limited by reference to racial or any other
> distinguishing characteristics—see Liddell & Scott's Greek-English
> Lexicon (8th edition)

**The official UK statistical body and the general structure of its surveys as they relate to ethnicity**

In the United Kingdom the official body which gathers and publishes statistics is the [Office for National Statistics](https://www.ons.gov.uk/).

Among other things it conducts a census every 10 years which everyone is required to complete. From 1991 census has asked questions about *ethnicity*.

The style of the ethnicity question used by ONS in the census is often also found in use by government departments and other public bodies (in the employment field) and is used by larger private companies.

The Ethnicity question is presented in the form of two large boxes (there is also a three, four and five large box versions but I will concentrate initially on the two large box version for simplicity of explanation - my question is pertinent whichever version is used).

The first large box contains a tickbox list containing e.g.

*English*

*Scottish*

*Welsh*

*Irish*

and ending with a *Any other White background (please specify)* box

Immediately to the right of that large box (or directly underneath it)  is another large box which contains a tickbox list of ethnicities. These can vary to a degree over time but neither *English*, *Scottish*, *Welsh* nor *Irish* is ever in this list in the second large box. At the bottom of the list in the second large box there is a tickbox saying *Any other non-White background (please specify)*

The instructions say you can only choose one large box and only one box within that so that when statistics are presented in, for example, a pie chart ([see here for example](https://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/ukgwa/20160105160709/http:/www.ons.gov.uk/ons/resources/figure1_tcm77-290598.png)) the slices of the pie will be distinct and not overlap.

This means that the last option in each large box which says *any other XXX background* carries the meaning of *any other XXX background not covered in any of the above* rather than *any other way you would like to describe your XXX background*. A consequence of this is that the presence or absence of a particular predefined option can have a strong influence on the answer given. For example take the case of someone who considers themselves a Kerryman first and foremost, and only secondarily as Irish. If neither *Kerryman* nor *Irish* are in the predefined list in the large box they are completing they might tick *Any other...* and write *Kerryman*. But if *Irish* is in the predefined list and *Kerryman* is not they would tick *Irish* because although they identify with additional ethnicities it would not be true to say that their ethnicity is **other than** - i.e. not - *Irish*.

**Some information about the United Kingdom for those not familiar with it**

By way background for those not familiar with the United Kingdom, the UK is a unitary state which consists of the island of Great Britain and the north-east corner of the island of Ireland which is called Northern Ireland. Great Britain contains three countries England, Wales, and Scotland but, as you would expect, people who grew up in Wales, for example, or whose parents identify as Welsh, or for some other reason feel an affinity to Wales might describe themselves as Welsh even if they currently reside in England. Everyone who is Welsh, Scottish or English would describe themselves as British but people vary as to what they initially describe themselves as when asked - e.g. whether they immediately say *British* or immediately say e.g. *Scottish*. Most English people (and Welsh and Scottish people) have a light skin tone (which the ONS calls "white"). Historically (including before the emergence of English as a fully-fledged ethnicity with its own language) there have always been a minority of people on the island of Great Britain with noticeably darker skin tone (which the ONS calls "black") but  because of intermarriage the number of people with distinctly darker than average skin remained relatively low until about 300 years ago when identifiable groups of people with dark skin emerged particularly in Liverpool and Cardiff and immigration in the last 100 years has increased that small minority to a large minority. Up until just over 200 years ago the whole of the island of Ireland was a single country - the Kingdom of Ireland. The Kingdom of Ireland and the Kingdom of Great Britain were then united as the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Ireland. About 100 years ago the majority of the land mass of Ireland became a separate state, the Republic of Ireland, but Northern Ireland remained part of the UK (now renamed the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland). Although some people in Northern Ireland might give Northern Irish (or "Ulster") as their ethnic identity, because the partition of the island of Ireland is relatively recent most people either identify as British or Irish. Of those who identify as Irish in Northern Ireland, the majority would actually prefer Northern Ireland to be part of the Republic of Ireland if that were to be possible and it is important for them to give their ethnicity as *Irish* and not *Northern Irish* - i.e. they do not want their expression of ethnicity to be artificially constrained to a subset of how they see themselves.

**The experience of someone filling in the classic two large box survey form**

If you consider an English person who is black filling in the Ethnicity question it is immediately apparent to them that the first large box is not for them. Usually the first large box will actually be headed *White* (and the second large box will be headed *non-White*) but even if the first large box is not headed *White* it is obvious from the last tickbox of the list

*Any* **other** *White background (please specify)*

that all the boxes above, including *English* are to be understood as only being appropriate for those who are white.

Turning to the second large box, *English* is not among the options listed (nor are *Scottish*, *Welsh* or *Irish*) but *Caribbean* is. At the bottom of the list it allows you to specify as an ethnicity

*Any other non-White background (please specify)*

but the words *any other* suggest that if any of the options listed above applies in any way that should be ticked and the *any other* option should not be ticked unless all the options listed above it are completely inapplicable. Most black people in the UK now are descendants of those who came to the UK from Caribbean islands within the last 70 years and may well consider themselves to have a Caribbean ethnicity as well as English, Scottish or Welsh etc. It is not necessary to prioritise ethnicities but even if they feel that *English* is their primary ethnicity they are likely to feel that they should tick Caribbean if that is *one* of their ethnicities and, having chosen that, they may feel that it does not seem right to choose *any other* instead (the instructions say *tick one box only*) even if they do not consider *Caribbean* to be their main ethnicity.

In any event writing *English* under *any other non-White background* does not seem right here because, whilst there are millions of English people who are black, *English* as a term is not itself a specifically *non-White background*

You would not want to put *Black English* because *Black English* is not an ethnicity. The whole idea of an ethnic group is that it is a group. Saying, in effect, *you can't be part of our group but we will set up another group a bit like ours for people with skin like yours* (as the ONS has actually done on more recent surveys with the *Black British* option) is not the same. This is similar to the position of a person with *Irish* ethnicity in Northern Ireland who objects to their expression of ethnicity being constrained to the subset *Northern Irish*.

This general proposition - that e.g. *Black English* is not a commonly recognised ethnicity - seems to be confirmed by [ONS research](https://www.ons.gov.uk/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/nationalidentityethnicgrouplanguageandreligionquestiondevelopmentforcensus2021#research-that-led-to-the-recommended-census-2021-question-designs) into terms such as *Black Welsh* which concluded:

> The combination of ethnic minority and UK identity, such as “Black
> Welsh”, was noticed in England, but was rarely noticed by ethnic
> minority respondents.

Some people (I imagine probably not from the UK) have given answers to this Politics SE question implying that the above ONS research shows that everyone in the UK thinks that you can only be of English (or Welsh) ethnicity if you are "white". This is a misunderstanding. It is precisely because Welsh and English ethnicity is not (and never has been) restricted to particular skin tones that Black Welsh is not recognised as a specific ethnicity - i.e. you can be *black and ethnically Welsh* but not *Black Welsh* as a specific ethnicity. Similarly you can be a blue-eyed Welshman but *Blue Welsh* is not an ethnicity.

**The Ethnicity question in the 2021 Census form**

The above describes the classic two large box system but more recently there seems to have developed a five large box version which can be seen in the [paper version of the 2021 Census](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/census2021paperquestionnaires/householdenglandpdf.pdf)

Sometimes surveys are taken face to face and the [ONS Guidance](https://www.ons.gov.uk/methodology/classificationsandstandards/measuringequality/ethnicgroupnationalidentityandreligion) states:

> **What instruction should be used when asking the ethnic group question
> in a face-to-face interviewer-led survey and self-completion survey?**
>
> It is recommended that the ethnic group question will be asked in a
> way that allows the respondent to see all possible response options
> before making their decision. Therefore, in face-to-face
> interviewer-led surveys, a single show card should be used that
> presents all response options. The interviewer should then ask the
> respondent to select the option that best describes their ethnic group
> or background.

This makes clear that the fact that a black person inevitably sees, on the paper census form, a box headed *White* which includes within it the word *English* - thus suggesting that only white people can be English - is a deliberate design feature which it is important to show to all respondents before they state their ethnicity.

**Completing the 2021 Census online**

If you use the online version the gist of the first question is *Are you White, Black, Asian or something else?*

[Initial Screen](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/nationalidentityethnicgrouplanguageandreligionquestiondevelopmentforcensus2021/052ce125.png)

If you select *White* you are then given *English* as an option

[Further Screen if White is selected](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/nationalidentityethnicgrouplanguageandreligionquestiondevelopmentforcensus2021/397d123e.png)

But if you select *Black* (or *Asian* or any other high-level option other than *White*) you are taken to a screen which does not have *English* as an option. If you do this you will not have seen the screen which suggests that English is specific to the White group but you will be given a number of predefined options none of which is English.

[Further Screen if Black is selected](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/nationalidentityethnicgrouplanguageandreligionquestiondevelopmentforcensus2021/6ba0beac.png)

So the survey form and online version provided by the ONS apparently does not cater for people who are not "white" who regard themselves as  English. (The same applies to Scottish and Welsh.)

**Note: the domicile question and it recent renaming**

In order to ensure that nobody is missed off the census or double counted each household is required to fill it in based on who was present in the household on a ONS-specified date. Of course some people present in a household on a particular date may be staying there only temporarily so censuses have always asked about each person's domicile - i.e. where they usually live or where they call home. This question about domicile has, in the 2021 census been named "national identity" which may be liable to confuse because "identity" normally refers to something such as ethnicity rather than mere domicile but ONS notes make clear that this question is not about ethnicity. It is ["not dependent on your ethnic group or citizenship".](https://census.gov.uk/help/how-to-answer-questions/paper-questions-help/how-would-you-describe-your-national-identity) Of course not everyone reads the ONS notes and one might speculate as to why this question has been renamed so that it sounds a bit like *ethnicity* and has been placed immediately before the actual *ethnicity* question. What is clear is that if a black person enters *English* as an answer to this question it will have no effect on the recording of their *ethnicity*

**The practice in other countries**

I don't know about every other country but I know that France does not ask about ethnicity and [most other EU member states do not either](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/default/files/data_collection_in_the_field_of_ethnicity.pdf). The [USA](https://www.census.gov/topics/population/race/about.html) allows those answering to select any ethnicity or ethnicities in any combination - unlike with the UK ONS no combinations are ruled out or made difficult to select.

**Conclusion**

Prominent black Members of the UK Parliament have objected to people telling them that they cannot be English if they are black. [In March 2021 David Lammy MP told a caller](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/david-lammy-lbc-african-caribbean-english-b1824029.html) who said that he could not be English because he was black:

> I want my identities recognised appropriately ... I’m of African
> descent, African-Caribbean descent but I am English.

So my question is

**What is the rationale of preventing English people who are black (or indeed any English person with a skin tone darker than what the ONS regards as "white") saying on the census form (or in other surveys/questionnaires based on the same structure) that they are of English ethnicity?**

Comment: Note that in the most recent census, a question on national identity, including all the consistuent countries of the UK was asked immediately before the request for ethnicity.

Comment: @origimbo The ONS notes makes clear that that question is about domicile but the use of the word "identity" might suggest - to someone who does not read the notes - that it is about ethnicity. What is the purpose of renaming it and placing it immediately before the ethnicity question? Is it a sort of consolation prize - i.e. you can't say you have English ethnicity but we will allow you to say that England is your home!

Comment: The question-title asks why people aren't _allowed_ to make a selection, but you're actually asking why it's a write-in rather than pre-defined, right?

Comment: Separately, this question's kind of a big wall-of-words without much formatting.  Seems like you might be able to significantly streamline it by showing [the image of the relevant survey-question](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/nationalidentityethnicgrouplanguageandreligionquestiondevelopmentforcensus2021/6ba0beac.png), then asking why the option isn't pre-defined.  Commentary and explanations of the background/context could go after that, helping to organize.

Comment: @Nat I have added some headings now. I am asking why it isn't *allowed* and I don't think this is an exaggeration. If you read through the question, hopefully a bit easier with the headings, I think you will see what I mean. Essentially once you select *black* (which is the initial gateway question) the way subsequent questions are worded makes clear that you are expected to write in a description which is unique to black people and not a word like *English* which includes people of all skin tones. Obviously as it  is a piece of paper there is nothing to *physically* stop you writing English.

Comment: I think this question is getting out of control.  It is rapidly becoming a thesis on the nature of ethnicity in the united kingdom. And as such it is becoming less useful.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you are referring to the quotation at the start of the question (from the case of *Mandla v Lee*) I have attempted to set out the salient points whilst being economical with the number of words. But anyone can click on the link I have provided and see the original.

Comment: @Nemo. I deleted my previous Comments: they weren't much help and in the end, your exposition remains excellent; thanks! Isn't ONS asserting that even in this most mongrel nation, ethnicity runs so much deeper than upbringing that no, newlyweds can't join, not Danish or French, Hungarian or Iberian, even the Germans who gave us "English" through Anglo-Saxon. Even by the third or fourth generation, Alphabetian descendants have lost all distinguishing features. Colour remains outside any choices of clothes and customs.

Answer (score 28):

I'm not going to try and answer the question of how it *should* be phrased, but I can point you to a resource the ONS publishes explaining their own reasoning. Emphasis mine.

https://www.ons.gov.uk/census/censustransformationprogramme/questiondevelopment/nationalidentityethnicgrouplanguageandreligionquestiondevelopmentforcensus2021#research-that-led-to-the-recommended-census-2021-question-designs

> **Ethnic group high-level category descriptions**
>
> We tested four versions of the two high-level category descriptions at the first  stage of the ethnic group question:
>
> - version 1: “Asian or Asian British” and “Black, Black British, Caribbean or African”
> - version 2: “Asian, Asian Welsh or Asian British” and “Black, Black Welsh, Black British, Caribbean or African”
> - version 3: “Asian or Asian British, including Asian Welsh” and “Black, Black British, including Black Welsh, Caribbean or African”
> - version 4: “Asian or Asian Welsh, English, Scottish, Northern Irish or British” and “Black, Black Welsh, English, Scottish, Northern Irish or British, Caribbean or African” (in locations in England “English” was listed before “Welsh”)
>
> **When additional high-level identities were included in the response categories, respondents were more likely to record an identity that was inconsistent with how they described themselves. This was more likely depending on how many words were included in the response categories. The combination of ethnic minority and UK identity, such as “Black Welsh”, was noticed in England, but was rarely noticed by ethnic minority respondents.**
>
> Following this testing, we have recommended using the version 2 phrasing, with the high-level categories “Asian, Asian Welsh or Asian British” and “Black, Black Welsh, Black British, Caribbean or African”. These will appear on the questionnaire in Wales only.

Comment: Note that the 2021 census is structured somewhat differently from the 1991 one, and has an entire separate question on national identity.

Comment: That explains why e.g. *Black English* is not presented as a predefined ethnicity (i.e. nobody recognises *Black English* as an ethnicity) but it does not explain why a black person is prevented from self-identifying as being of *English* ethnicity.

Comment: An analogy to try to illustrate what I mean. Supposing the ONS survey prevented people with blond hair identifying as having an English ethnicity (they don't but this is just a example to illustrate the point) and the question is asked - why is that? It would not be a satisfactory explanation to say that *Blond English* is not a widely recognised ethnicity.

Comment: @Nemo because it isn't an *English* ethnicity, it's *White (English)*, split between a heading and a radio button.

Comment: @Nemo There's two possibilities for your hypothetical, one where *White (English)* is the only ethnicity where *English* is a part, which corresponds to "*Blond English* is not a widely recognised ethnicity.", but equally plausible is "*Blond (English)* is a widely recognised ethnicity." and the survey is written to be inclusive of that, so you get english as a sub-option for blondes as well as whites

Comment: @Nemo if we are really splitting hairs, There's one selection that they care about, with 5 labels. I would guess that their testing found that including those labels stopped a bunch of people writing a UK nationality in the "other" box. It's hard to write a survey that's understood *in the same way* by millions of people.

Comment: Another analogy. Suppose the questions are about games. The White box lists draughts, tennis etc. and "any other white game". The Black box lists poker etc. and "and other black game". Say you play chess. Chess is not a "black game" (anybody can play that or any other game). You query this and the answer is "we conducted a test on a sample audience and there was not much recognition of the game called **black chess**". Doesn't make any sense does it?

Comment: @Nemo It doesn't have to make sense, it doesn't have to be consistent. It has to confuse as few people as possible.

Comment: @Caleth You seem to be saying that the ONS has no overall rationale for this.

Comment: @Nemo no, I am saying that their rationale is for as many respondents to the survey to understand how to answer the questions in the same way as the ONS do. "respondents were more likely to record an identity that was inconsistent with how they described themselves"

Comment: @Caleth *the same way as ONS do* yes, but what is the rationale for ONS doing it the way they dio?

Comment: @Nemo There's ambiguity in version 4. The intended grouping is "Black, Black (Welsh, English, Scottish, Northern Irish or British), Caribbean or African", but you can mistakenly think it "Black, (Black Welsh), English, Scottish, Northern Irish or British, Caribbean or African"

Comment: @Nemo "what is the rationale for ONS doing it the way they dio" The tested it, and this was the least confusing phrasing

Comment: @Caleth (1) ONS have a rationale for classifying people into certain categories. (2) that influences the design of their surveys. You are concentrating on (2) - as is this answer -but the question is about (1).

Comment: @Nemo yes, they consider "Welsh, English, Scottish, Northern Irish or British" to be interchangeable subcategories of "White", "Asian" and "Black", and have crafted a survey to best capture that. Or at least that's what I can see from your picture links. Have you got an example where those are split up?

Answer (score 20):

My impression as a (white) immigrant to the UK is English/Scottish/Welsh identity is treated rather differently from British. While Britishness is a rather inclusive concept, the individual national ethnicities are much less so, and much more tied to ancestry. For me personally, this means that after having lived in the UK for a decade now, I feel very much on the way to becoming British, but I doubt that I will ever be Welsh. I've met people who's great-grandparents moved to England from Ireland, who identifed as British, but certaintly not as English; or Scottish folks who were born and raised in Yorkshire.

In the case of Black people who moved to Great Britain from the Caribbean in the 50s/60s and their descendents, it means that while they are obviously British, it is much less clear whether they are English/Welsh/Scottish. If one of them tells me they are, I'll believe them, but it would also surprise me a bit. This seems to be the same attitude reflected in the ONS material: They operate under the default assumption that English people are white, but you can give answers disagreeing with this.

Comment: ...but those people who moved to England in the 50s and 60s may have had children. I know it was a racist time, but you can't tell me there were zero children who might plausibly check more than one box. I mean, what shall Harry and Meghan's kids put? (OK, realistically, "American", since it seems that's where they will grow up, but you get my meaning.)

Comment: For the record, as an Asian third-generation immigrant (both my parents and I born in England), I would consider my Northern Englishness to be a much more significant part of my identity than my "Britishness", whatever that vague notion is. To be more specific, I would describe my ethnicity as non-English (Pakistani specifically) and my national identity as English - although I do usually tick British-Pakistani on forms because that's always been the default selection for someone of my background and I've never thought about it much beyond that.

Comment: @Arno *British* can be a wider term. People in the British Channel Islands, for example, are British although they are outside the UK. The same applies to the British colonies around the world - most of them are sovereign nations now rather than colonies but until the 1950s/1960s "the Sun never set on the British Empire".

Answer (score 7):

They are specifically asking about ethnicity.  It really comes down to a rather clumsy mix of (a) race and (b) for white people, which part of Europe your ancestors were from.  The question is about trying to distinguish between different "shades" of white.  So it's distinguishing between white people whose ancestors immigrated from Ireland, white people whose ancestors have been in Britain for as long as anybody knows, or white people from other places.

In that context, "black British" doesn't make a lot of sense.  And, yes, there have been black people in Britain since Roman times.  Any attempt to group people into neat categories is always a minefield.

Comment: This works until people have two parents (not to mention 4 grandparents, etc.). Even if the census creators swoon at the idea of a mixed white+non-white couple, I can't believe no one of mixed Scottish/Irish heritage hasn't complained yet in an impossible-to-ignore manner.

Comment: It does seem as if, whatever the courts said, the ONS is using "ethnicity" here simply as a synonym for "race" or "ancestry", rather than anything about culture or allegiance.  If so, as @user3067860 says, subdividing "White" into English, Scottish, Irish, Welsh and Other is a bit silly, because there's so much mobility between the countries that by that rule *most* UK people count as "White, other (British)".  Go back a few generations and my ancestors were scattered across all four, and I suspect that's not unusual.  (My dad calls himself Welsh when England are losing at football  :-D  )

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**

The ONS is attempting to capture race statistics according to how a racist would classify people. It is interested in self-identification of ethnicity primarily as a proxy for skin tone.

**Long Answer**

**Collecting data according to racist categories**

A 2017 report by the European Commission [*Data collection in the field of ethnicity*](https://ec.europa.eu/info/sites/default/files/data_collection_in_the_field_of_ethnicity.pdf) states that:

> In order to measure (in)equality, it may be as important to identify
> the perceived racial and ethnic origin as the one self-identified.

This appears to be a widely held view. The rationale is that if statistics are to be useful in helping to examine the effects of discrimination, and the effectiveness of measures to combat discrimination, it is necessary to classify people from the discriminator’s point of view. If someone of Caribbean descent who self-identifies as English or British is discriminated against it will not be, so the theory goes, because they are English or British but rather because of the colour of their skin so it is believed that, one way or another, statisticians need to record skin tone.

This appears to reflect the approach of ONS:

> the ethnic group question was never ‘intended to establish the
> “ethnic” composition of the population as it might be understood by
> sociologists, anthropologists and historians,’ rather, to ‘capture in
> a common sense or pragmatic way the categories of person that were
> likely to be victims of “racial” discrimination

ONS Information paper: [*Deciding which tick-boxes to add to the ethnic group
question in the 2011 England and Wales Census*](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/census/2011census/howourcensusworks/howweplannedthe2011census/questionnairedevelopment/finalisingthe2011questionnaire/ethnicgroupprioritisationtool_tcm77-183986.pdf)

**The political unacceptability of questions about skin tone and the co-incidence of the Windrush proxy**

It is obvious that actually asking people to state their skin tone would be completely unacceptable as well as being unreliable, so a proxy has to be found – i.e. a question or series of questions has to be devised which are just about acceptable and which are capable of being processed so as to produce statistics for skin tone.

After World War II as many former British colonies were in the process of becoming independent the British Nationality Act 1948 was passed one of the purposes of which was to cater for the transition of the people in each colony from being British citizens to having a separate citizenship of the newly independent country. The citizenship laws passed by newly independent countries did not always make everyone in them citizens of the country so there was a need to ensure that nobody would be left stateless. An unintended consequence of the 1948 Act was that it ended up giving [800 million people around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_immigration_to_the_United_Kingdom) the right to emigrate to the United Kingdom.

Not all 800m came to the UK, of course, but the fact that they could do so, without visas, meant that they the became a recruiting ground for UK government attempts to help fill gaps in the UK labour market for both skilled and unskilled jobs, including in public services such as the newly created National Health Service and London Transport, by encouraging economic migration. Many people were specifically brought to the UK on ships: notably the *Empire Windrush* in 1948, which sailed from the Caribbean, and those who came to the UK from the Caribbean in the 1950s and 1960 are commonly referred to as the *Windrush Generation* (even if they did not arrive on that particular ship). But in 1971 the Immigration Act 1971 introduced restrictions on immigration from what were then Commonwealth countries.

This historical phenomenon – large scale immigration from Caribbean islands over a relatively short period of time – was a gift to any statistician wanting to measure the prevalence of particular skin tones without actually having to ask what would have obviously been an unacceptable question. The *Windrush* immigration increased the proportion of the UK population who were “black” so much that asking where a respondent was born and where their parents were born was thought to be a reasonable proxy for recording skin tone.

> Though the census was the most obvious vehicle to gather information
> on both the extent of racial discrimination and the effectiveness of
> the Race Relations Acts of the 1960s, it was not considered feasible
> to ask a question on race or ethnic identity in preparation for the
> 1971 census. The assertion of Dale and Holdsworth ( 1997 ) that the
> General Register Office (the predecessor of the Office of Population
> Censuses and Surveys) was adamant that such a question be neither
> asked nor answered is not entirely correct. **The decision to include a
> question on parents’ country of birth – rather than the previously
> asked question about the respondents’ ‘country of origin’ or a direct
> question on race or ethnicity – reveals the internal politicking at
> work within the state apparatus.** …the need for racial data was
> acknowledged by senior Home Office bureaucrat Jack Howard-Drake, who
> wrote in a memo that **his initial concern surrounded ‘the impossibility
> of defining immigrant or colour in precise terms,’** but that he was
> ‘now not so sure that this view is correct,’ noting that ‘[with] the
> emergence of the second generation it will become increasingly
> important for us to have as much statistical information as we can
> about the coloured minority in the United Kingdom’. In early 1968 the
> matter was referred to the Statistical Policy Committee for Ministers
> to decide; therein, the majority of the Committee were clearly in
> favour of collecting information about racial origin and decided to
> make the suggestion at the upcoming Home Affairs Committee meeting. At
> this meeting the Minister of Health proposed that a question on ethnic
> origin be included on the census, but the Secretary of State recorded
> his concern about the ‘political difficulties’ that would result, and
> **the decision to include a question on ‘parents’ country of origin’
> rather than a direct question on race was decided at the Ministerial
> level though Cabinet acknowledged that using this proxy would not
> provide accurate information…**  These ‘considerable political
> implications’ were many: first, **British bureaucrats and Ministers
> alike felt that it was impossible to define race or colour in the
> precise terms required for a statistical exercise such as the census.**
> Second, **there was a clear concern that asking a direct question on
> race or colour would be perceived as offensive to both ‘coloured’ and
> white respondents.** The proposal to instead ask the country of origin
> of the respondent’s parents was more familiar, and thus less
> controversial, since the 1961 census asked for country of birth with
> the intention of identifying immigrants to the United Kingdom. The
> 1971 question, designed to identify the children of these immigrants,
> was not [an] extreme break from tradition… the 1971 census collected
> information on both the respondent’s country of birth (as in the 1961
> census) and his or her parent’s country of birth in order to gauge the
> approximate size of the racial population. It was acknowledged at the
> time – and indeed, throughout the policy-making process – that this
> method would be inaccurate for enumerating those white Britons who
> happened to be born in colonies overseas, pockets of the historic (and
> indigenous) Black British population, in, for example, Cardiff and
> Liverpool and people of mixed-race.

[*The Ethnic Question: Census Politics in Great Britain*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81534687.pdf) Debra Thompson

**Thinking the unthinkable: a census question based on classification by skin tone**

Not only was the 1971 proxy question less reliable than hoped but it was clear that, being dependant on the *Windrush* phenomenon, it would become less and less reliable as time moved on. Those in government convinced of the need to collect statistics on skin tone eventually came to think the unthinkable, that respondents might actually be asked questions which could not be wholly disguised. Whilst both “black” and “white” respondents were bound to be offended by such questions, it was thought that “black” respondents would be the most resistant and initial testing of prototype questions started there.

> Fieldwork by the Office of Population Censuses and Surveys began in
> 1975, and a variety of different forms of question were tried out in
> sample surveys designed to test the methodology. The basic form of the
> first question devised was: *Race or ethnic group. Please tick the
> appropriate box to show the race or ethnic group to which the person
> belongs, or from which the person is descended.* The boxes read: *1.
> White. 2. West Indian
> 3. African 4. Arab 5. Chinese 6. Indian
> 7. Pakistani 8. Bangladeshi 9. Sri Lankan
> 10. Any other race or ethnic group, or if of mixed racial or ethnic descent (please describe below)….*
>
> **This version could not, however, be used in the census because the
> inclusion of a question which referred to colour (in this case
> “white”) was judged not appropriate for a government inquiry which was
> compulsory.** A different version was therefore produced which was used
> in the 1979 Test Census, a voluntary enumeration covering the entire
> London Borough of Haringey (O.P.C.S. (1981)). The Haringey Test Census
> incorporated a split—half design. Half of all schedules included
> questions asked in the 1971 Census of Population about country of
> birth and country of birth of father and of mother. The other half
> included a modification of the direct question on race and ethnicity
> which read:
>
> *11. Racial or ethnic group. Please tick the appropriate box to show the racial or ethnic group to which the person belongs. If the person
> was born in the United Kingdom of West Indian, African, Asian, Chinese
> or “Other European” descent, please tick one of the boxes numbered 2
> to 10 to show the group from which the person was descended. The boxes
> read: 1. English, Welsh, Scottish or Irish 2. Other European 3. West
> Indian or Guayanese 4. African 5. Indian 6. Pakistani
> 7. Bangladeshi 8. Arab 9. Chinese
> 10. Any other racial or ethnic group, or if of mixed racial or ethnic descent (please describe below).*
>
> **The results of the test census were seriously affected by hostility
> towards the questions on racial or ethnic group**, parents’ birthplaces
> and own country of birth, expressed by certain local black
> organizations and given publicity in the media. In particular 25,000
> copies of a leaﬂet were said to have been distributed linking these
> questions to alleged plans for new nationality laws that *“would make
> nationality dependent on your parents’ nationality, not where you
> were born ..... If we say now who is or is not of British descent, we
> may one day be asked to ‘go home’ if we were born here or not”.* In the
> event only…  one-quarter of West Indian households and two-fifths of
> households originating from the Indian subcontinent filled in the test
> census form. The quality of the answers on the completed forms was
> also much inferior to that obtained in previous tests in the period
> 1975-1978. Of the West Indians and Asians who did complete the form,
> as many as one-third said in a follow-up interview that they objected
> in principle to the inclusion of these questions in the next census. '
> Even greater objections were expressed to the parents’ country of
> birth question. **The largest proportion of errors occurred in recording
> information about second generation U.K.- born persons arising from
> ambiguity about what “English, etc.” in the first box really meant.**
> This applied both to people of West Indian and Asian descent and to
> people of continental European descent. **The actual 1981 British Census
> did not include a direct question on race and ethnicity or on parents’
> country of birth. The decision to leave such questions out was taken
> at political level by ministers.**

[*A Controversial Census Topic: Race and
Ethnicity in the British Census*](https://www.scb.se/contentassets/ca21efb41fee47d293bbee5bf7be7fb3/a-controversial-census-topic-race-and-ethnicity-in-the-british-census.pdf)
Martin Bulmer

By the time "ethnicity"/race was first included as a census question - in the 1991 census - it had become clear to the ONS that the only way to make a skin-tone question even half acceptable was to elide it with an "ethnicity" question. The ONS is not interested or, at least, not primarily interested in self-identified ethnicity but need to use it to soften the otherwise unacceptable question about skin colour.

**Conclusion**

This is why the ONS could never accept an ethnicity question not linked to skin colour as it would force them to either abandon the objective of collecting data on skin colour or else to ask a stark additional standalone skin colour question which would be unacceptable.

I have not been able to find any unambiguous acknowledgement of this rationale in ONS publications but it seems to me to follow logically from the history as explained above and is consistent with the ONS statement that:

> the ethnic group question was never ‘intended to establish the
> “ethnic” composition of the population as it might be understood by
> sociologists, anthropologists and historians,’ rather, to ‘capture in
> a common sense or pragmatic way the categories of person that were
> likely to be victims of “racial” discrimination